How to implement Session storage in flet for mobile
There is an article about Session Storage in the official flat documentation, but it is quite small and incomprehensible for beginners. There are also no examples related to flet. I know that in flutter there is a session store implementation with explanations based on some simple program. Can you explain with an example how to create session stores? Please note that the future application will be made on Android.

This one help you to remove current view in views and help to navigate last page u visited. This is simple way to navigate go back last page.
def view_pop(view):
    page.views.pop()
    top_view = page.views[-1]
    page.go(top_view.route)

page.on_route_change = route_change
page.on_view_pop = view_pop
page.go(page.route)

